# Resource to improve ability to interpret and understand formulas and algorithms

Tags: algorithms, self-learning, learning

I wasn't sure whether this belonged here or on StackOverflow but here goes:
I've been doing a lot of research into algorithms recently and I've found that my inability to properly interpret and understand some of the formulas and algorithms is starting to impede my ability to get anything meaningful enough to go off and write a program to implement the algorithms described.

Is there any resource (online prefered but books are ok) you could recommend I use that is for total beginners? Even though I'm (mainly) a programmer, I don't think knowing 5+ languages are worth anything unless I can change the simple fact that my mathematical abilities are merely average.

I'd prefer something that starts off utterly simple and builds up to the more complex/abstract stuff. If it had Pseudo code or an actual implementation, even better. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

I think "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen is the standard reference for this. Also, I found "Concrete Mathematics - A Foundation for Computer Science" to be very enjoyable. The first one really concentrates on the theory of algorithms while the second one is more about mathematics.

Comment: Weirdly enough I've ordered the first one already, should be delivered today. Slightly worried about its size though, I'm not sure I can read all of that